# Create a tag synonym for orchard and orchardcms

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

So there are two tags for [Orchard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchard_Project):

- [orchardcms](/questions/tagged/orchardcms)
- [orchard](/questions/tagged/orchard)

I'm assuming they're the same thing, and it would be nice if someone created a synonym.

I just really like Orchard and would like to see more people participate about it here, as opposed to the mailing list and the not so great [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified that all the [orchard](/questions/tagged/orchard) questions were really [orchardcms](/questions/tagged/orchardcms) questions and retagged them.  There are currently no [orchard](/questions/tagged/orchard) questions.

However, creating the "orchard" synonym for the "orchardcms" tag requires more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 on the tag.

See [Top Users for orchardcms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orchardcms/topusers).  There is currently only one user who qualifies!  ([User Sohnee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/sohnee))

You might invite him into a chat and ask him to propose the synonym.  But there currently only 2 other users who can up-vote it if he does.  It requires 4 up-votes to get approved.

Alternatively, you *might* flag this answer and ask a moderator to do it.  Note that meta moderators and SO moderators are not necessarily the same, IIRC.

Comment: +1 awesome, thanks! I was thinking of re-tagging myself! How do i invite him to chat?

Comment: @giddy, see my revised answer.  I realized that there aren't enough high-rep users on that tag to get a synonym the regular way.  Your only choices are (1) wait and gain rep, (2) Get a moderator to do it, (3) lobby for a more egalitarian way to create synonyms (like the recent edit-mechanism changes).

Comment: I think I'll go with (2) at the moment, will flag your answer (or my question?) I will also try contacting darin who is on the top orchard users, back to my question, I'm not familiar with any option to **invite** a user to chat?

Comment: Re chat invites:  I haven't done it, but according to the [Chat faq](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq), you would create a chatroom and then "If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the room edit menu."  I'll go try to invite you, now.

Comment: ah ok, nope I don't see any invite yet here, on SO or meta?

Comment: Just figured out how to send it, you might have to be active on SO to see it?

Comment: @brock so it seems like the orchard tag is gone/delete, maybe because you retagged so no question has it? Anyway, thanks for the help! =)  Enjoy your bounty!